# How to calculate average of data in vba

Tags: excel, vba

how to get average data using VBA Script.

example

```
   Dim Data  As Double
   Dim Data2 As Double
   Dim Data3 As Double

   Data = 15.66   // how to get Data = 16
   Data2 = 9.01   // how to get Data2 = 9
   Data3 = 45     // how to get Data3 = 45
```

Comment: `Application.Round`?

Comment: Do you need the `Average` as the question title states, or only rounding the number? Then, why declaring the variable `As String` and fill them with numbers? Anyhow, `Dim Data,Data2,Data3 as String` declares first variable `As Variant` and only the last one `As String`...